# How to output the results of 2 different cells into a single cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting, cell-format

I am trying to get D5 and D6 into cell C6 so that I looks like this ($15,000.00 - $25,000.00) The formula I used to do this is :

```
=DOLLAR(D5)&" - "&DOLLAR(D6)
```

My first question is, is there an easier/better way to accomplish this?

My second question, how will I remove the decimal places in C6, as the number formatting decimal spacer doesn't work for this situation?

Please see screen shot below.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/62QdURw]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 or Excel 2019 use TEXTJOIN and TEXT:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",,TEXT(D5:D6,"$#,##0"))
```

If using in Excel 2019 this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If older version then instead of DOLLAR() use TEXT:

```
=TEXT(D5,"$#,##0")&" - "&TEXT(D6,"$#,##0")
```

[image]